# Unload and escaping quotes in Redshift query

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I already looked at similar questions here on SO and on the official documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html).

I'd like to unload this query to s3

```
SELECT column_name, data_type
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  table_name = 'table_temp'
ORDER  BY ordinal_position;
```

with

```
UNLOAD ('SELECT column_name
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  table_name = 'table_temp'
ORDER  BY ordinal_position')   
to 's3://bucket/folder/' 
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=KEY;aws_secret_access_key=SECRET'
DELIMITER AS ',';
```

despite I tried several way to escape the single quote `\,\\,$,"` it seems I'm not able to achieve it. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If your query contains quotation marks (for example to enclose literal values), put the literal between two sets of single quotation marks—you must also enclose the query between single quotation marks:

```
('select * from venue where venuestate=''NV''')
```

Ref: [AWS Unload Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html)

Answer (score -1):

Why can't we achieve the same using:

```
UNLOAD ('SELECT column_name [or *]
FROM table_name [where clause]'
)   
to 's3://bucket/folder/' 
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=KEY;aws_secret_access_key=SECRET'
DELIMITER AS ',';
```

Comment: Is it an answer?

Comment: Yes. And it works. Is it a constraint to query information_schema and then pass `table_name` as a parameter? You can directly do a `select *` (or select some relevant columns) from the table itself, directly. The way I've mentioned in the answer above.

Comment: Inside the `UNLOAD` you are missing a single quote plus you're not telling from which table read.

Comment: I guess there is misunderstanding: the first query itself works, but when i try to unload to s3 I got the following Error `[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "a"`
So there is something about the escaping i need to do.